# If I do not need to breathe, do I still need my heart and lungs?

Tags: dnd-5e, unearthed-arcana, mystic

The [Mystic class from Unearthed Arcana](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UAMystic3.pdf) has the Adaptive Body discipline (page 10), which states:

> While focused on this discipline, you no longer need to eat, breathe...

So would I still need my heart and lungs since I have no use for them anymore? Can I just scoop out all of my internal organs since I also don't need my stomache as well? It could be helpful when playing dead or just hiding stuff inside of my body.

Comment: Hi Scaevitas, welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn about the site. Thanks for participating and happy gaming!

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: Ask your DM.

Long answer: There are no rules regarding your internal organs such as your heart or lungs so this would be entirely up to your DM.

How I would rule as the DM: You still need your heart to pump blood through your body for things other than breathing. Such as healing or distributing other things throughout your body. Your lungs I would say could be removed but you would likely take damage during the removal. Possibly lethal damage depending on where/how it's done.

Answer (score 4):

There is no specific rule for this, so it comes down to the DM's ruling.

I would note that the class does say:

> You   can focus   psionic energy  on  one of  your psionic    disciplines to  draw    ongoing benefits    from    it. As  a   bonus   action, you can choose  one of  your    psionic disciplines and gain    its psychic  focus benefit, which   is  detailed    in  that    discipline’s    description.    The benefit lasts   until   you are incapacitated   or  until   you use another  bonus  action  to  choose  a   different   focus   benefit.

So if your DM did allow this, then the first time you became incapacitated you would start dying. That's assuming you somehow managed to undergo the surgery to remove the organs without being incapacitated in the first place.

Comment: Also of note, falling asleep during a long rest is being incapacitated. So you would essentially suffocate in your sleep.